# How to create an array of strongly typed arrays?

Tags: typescript, variables, types, typed-arrays

I'm new in TS, but i didn't find answer for my question, so that's why I'm here)

I'm trying to create an array of arrays, that may contain only strongly typed data. For example like `[[string, number], [string, number], [string, number], ...]`

I tried to write such simple code:

```ts
let arr: Array<[string, number]> = [['dad\'s adidas', 123], ['moms gucci', 47]]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; i < arr[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(arr[i][j])
    }
    console.log('\n')
}
```

but the The compiler swears and give me this stupid error))

```bash
Uncaught SyntaxError C:\Users\sv25b\UbuntuProjects\WTF\main.ts:1
let arr: Array<[string, number]> = [['dad\'s adidas', 123], ['moms gucci', 47]]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: using npm in vs code

Comment: the vs code itself advised me to choose this compiler

Comment: So, what you did wrong is trying to run `typesccript` file by `javascript` runtime

Comment: You need to compile your code before running it

Comment: ah, directly tsc main.ts and only then start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. run `npm install tsx` - install [typescript runner](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx)

   - or install it globally with `npm install --global tsx`
2. run `npx tsx watch main.ts` to run your file, in watch mode (restarting on file save)

   - or `tsx watch main.ts` if you've installed tsx globally
   - or with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rxliuli.tsx
   - or with a launch configuration or tasks, that's long to explain ask if needed
3. see that your code infinitly logs `undefined`
4. fix `i < arr[i].length` to `j < arr[i].length`

Comment: Thank's, it work's. So, as I see, I have defined the array correctly, haven't it?